# Azure Service Fabric Cluster on a closed network stuck on Updating

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I have a template that sets up an Azure service fabric cluster successfully. *However, in order to complete the configuration, I need to open the NSG to the internet to access download.microsoft.com:80.* **This is forbidden in a production environment.** So far I have identified 23.40.68.76, 23.195.64.241, 23.66.100.156 as the possible IP's for download.microsoft.com.

The reason is due to ServiceFabricNodeBootstrapAgent attempting to download a Service fabric update:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="ServiceFabricNodeBootstrapAgent" /> 
  ...
- <EventData>
  <Data>Downloading fabric cab from http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/1/F/31F3FEEB-F073-4E27-A98B-8E691FF74F40/ServiceFabric.6.5.676.9590.cab to C:\windows\TEMP\ServiceFabric.6.5.676.9590.cab</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

I only have accesss to the vNet and NSG. The vNet is peered to a site network. Internet access is not allowed.

I need to be able to redirect this traffic to a impersonated site. I thought I could use the host file and redirect the traffic, but “download.microsoft.com” is a special url.

Is there a work-around strategy for this problem ?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Sadly the download center is not part of the ip range overview that you can get from microsoft [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519)

Answer (score 0):

Got answer from MS. They want me to open the firewall so the servers can download from port 80. This is a known issue. They might fix it in the future. Might not.

Answer (score -1):

Consider using [Azure Firewall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/overview#fqdn-tags) instead of the NSG to manage traffic. It is a Layer-7 firewall, that has a feature to allow or block traffic, based on the domain name.

Comment: I need to be able to redirect and impersonate not block

Comment: It could be useful to add that info to the question.